# mutate_impl error for a R code

Tags: r

Below is how my data looks like. I am trying to capture the %increase or decrease month by month for each Product, however getting an error.

```
Month, Product, Sales, diff
Jan, HP, 1000, 0
Feb, HP, 2000 , 1000
Mar, HP, 1300 , -700
April, HP, 5000 , 0
Jan, Samsung, 1200 , -3800
Feb, Samsung, 2500 , 1300
Mar, Samsung, 1100 , -1400
April, Samsung, 4500 , 3400
```

I am trying the below code.

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(Product) %>%
  mutate(PCT= diff/lag(Sales, 1))
```

**Below is the error i am getting.**

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots)
  column 'PCT' must be length 36 (the group size) or one, not 1200
```

Not sure what i am missing. Leads would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: It is working fine for me with the data showed.  try with `%>% dplyr::mutate(PCT = diff/dplyr::lag(Sales, 1))`

Comment: Thanks.. but the code that you have mentioned does not specify the group condition(Product). how will it identify product as the grouping condition?

Comment: I meant to replace only that part after the `group_by` i.e. `df %>% group_by(Product) %>% dplyr::mutate(PCT = diff/dplyr::lag(Sales, 1))`

Comment: Tried the same.. getting the same error :(

Comment: Please check the `str(df)` as I can't reproduce your error with the example you showed.  I am using `dplyr_0.7.4` on R 3.5.0